# Type-safe callback maps

Tags: typescript

I am trying to write a function that takes as an argument the name of a callback and returns a wrapped version of the callback.

The following is my attempted solution:

```
const callbacks = {
  alpha: (a: number, b: string) => {},
  bravo: (c: boolean, d: object) => {},
  charlie: (e: symbol, f: Date) => {},
} as const;

type CallbackMap = typeof callbacks;

const getWrappedCallback = <K extends keyof CallbackMap>(key: K) => {
  return (...args: Parameters<CallbackMap[K]>) => {
    console.log("Performing an additional preparation step");
    callbacks[key](...args); // Error: A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.
  };
};
```

As you can see, the second spread operation causes a compiler error because `args` is an array instead of a tuple. Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: TS can't follow the logic here; it's the same underlying problem as in [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581), and the recommended refactor is as described in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), where you write things explicitly as indexes into mapped types.  See [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WK9gMN) for how it would work. Does that fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz This is exactly the same issue and fully addresses my question. Thank you for pointing me towards your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript simply isn't able to follow the correlation between the type of `callbacks[key]` and the type of `args` in the single line of code `callbacks[key](...args)`.  The type `Parameters<CallbackMap[K]>` when `K` is a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter is essentially opaque to the compiler, because [the `Parameters` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) is implemented as a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html).  The compiler *defers* evaluation of generic conditional types.  Even though a human being understands that a function of type `T` should accept an argument list of type `Parameters<T>`, the compiler can only understand that for *specific* types `T`, not *generic* ones.

The issue is quite similar to the one discussed in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581), although that issue is about non-generic [unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), and yours is about a generic conditional type [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to a union.

---

One approach, if you just want to move forward quickly, is to use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to stop the compiler from complaining:

```
const getWrappedCallback = <K extends keyof CallbackMap>(key: K) => {
  return (...args: Parameters<CallbackMap[K]>) => {
    console.log("Performing an additional preparation step");
    (callbacks as any)[key](...args);
  };
};
```

But this isn't really type safe (if you made a mistake the compiler wouldn't catch it).  If you want to keep some type safety, then the recommended fix is similar to the fix for microsoft/TypeScript#30581, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  The compiler is able to understand certain generic operations as long as they are explicitly written in terms of [indexed accesses](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html).  So the goal is to rewrite `callbacks` so its type is in this form.

---

Here is one way to do it.  First, let's rename `callbacks` out of the way so that we can use the name later with the type TypeScript can understand:

```
const _callbacks = {
  alpha: (a: number, b: string) => { },
  bravo: (c: boolean, d: object) => { },
  charlie: (e: symbol, f: Date) => { },
} as const;    
type _CallbackMap = typeof _callbacks;
```

Now we can make some mapped types:

```
type CallParams = { [K in keyof _CallbackMap]: Parameters<_CallbackMap[K]> }
type CallRets = { [K in keyof _CallbackMap]: ReturnType<_CallbackMap[K]> }
```

These are the parameter lists and return types for `callbacks`, stored in separate types.  And now we can rebuild `callbacks` like this:

```
type CallbackMap = { [K in keyof _CallbackMap]: (...args: CallParams[K]) => CallRets[K] };
const callbacks: CallbackMap = _callbacks;
```

The `CallbackMap` type is, of course, completely equivalent to `_CallbackMap` (and that's why the assignment of `callbacks` from `_callbacks` works). But the difference is that `CallbackMap` is written explicitly in terms of a mapped type, so that later when we look up `key` in `callbacks`, the compiler will see it as a function of generic indexed access types (which it can follow) instead of a function of generic conditional types (which it can't):

```
const getWrappedCallback = <K extends keyof CallbackMap>(key: K) => {
  return (...args: CallParams[K]) => {
    const r = callbacks[key](...args); // okay
    // const r: CallRets[K]
  };
};
```

Now that compiles with no error.  The compiler sees that `args` is of type `CallParams[K]` and that `callbacks[key]` is of type `(...args: CallParams[K]) => CallRets[K]`, and those are identical types.  So the call is allowed, and the return type is `CallRets[K]` (not that you're using this, but if you were, it would keep track of that too).

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAOwhgtgpgzgDmAxlABAQRjKAnALigb2BRUQHsQZ9EwAbWgIyQGsYUBeQ4klOuACzAAuFAAphKEAFcIDHABoUDEVWwBLEAHMAlBwB8hFAF953Eg2xgAbmRGjEIhmTK0oYEIoAmIsgwBWUIi4uuwGBMamPKSC2LRqUHYJKDAAnrIuigBmIgAiYLhQIWER3Ea8bOSUuADcwNy4KXCoAMJ0jCwAsmBwHCgNTWSZpG1MiKy13JVUKJpQuADqlnBNnq30o8y9ADwA0ihQAB4FIJ5szFApgyhr7WNdcHqi5ykiO0VcUdhzUtggYgB0gLA2E0MBEAAVgZA5jgYFsbht7gBtHYAXT07yIURIUxcUH+tDImlEACJwThMmRsBANJpeH8wJ5PGpcGoKHQUHAvghLKyKMkCnASdpatixDR1iw2GBpSAUtokc9UaJAf9gaCRWZjKLtcAjMApvgAPoS26sXpY3i0AQScQiaSyBRKFS4dRaTElcyWGx2BxKZyudxeHz+QLBfSGEyTGJxJKiJKpdK0LK5fKFCPhKNlGWkChUCb9VBGhGdbq9QtXE0jKUFxotNqQywQNiccIolAaFDPSslu7dVEQqHQArYOHF6t9uAo9HGYCF65tABKcxbhnbne7Q3HksnA5Qy9wPxAABU61tt2bkWiDPq53WFzvmPcLSh139NygL4j+3ZVeqwQ+tCNpAMDTu8NwHqBaK6oawyPgBvZPmWnBVvBEywbMCxLCsiHbHshzHKcXYXFciH3I8zyvJi3BfIevwAkCIIIQ2Q5Qai1FRLirgEkSpLktglLUrS9K8EyLJsuAtCctyUJ8n8VBQEKmqcXm+DYL0pobKBSoqoxGo6iQAD0hm5lUKDYCIEErtOpS1EY1RAA)